# JQUery validation plugin for checking data availability

Tags: jquery

I am learning how to use JQuery validation plugin,
I got a simple input text field like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username">
```

But I don't know how to use this plugin to do some data availability tasks.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The [remote](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote) methods looks like the tool for the job. It makes requests to a URL you specify to implement server-side validation.